# Scheme converting a list to a String within a function

Tags: string, recursion, scheme, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am not sure how to convert a list to a string within a function when I recursively call it. For example, my code is as follows:

```
(define (pre-order T)
 (define (conv x)
    (cond ((number? x) (number->string x))
    ((char? x) (string x))))

(map-diff (lambda (x) (conv x)) T)

   (cond ((null? T) "")
    ((eq? (value T) #\+)
           (cons "+" (pre-order (right T))(pre-order (left T))))
     ((eq? (value T) #\*)
           (cons "*" (pre-order (right T))(pre-order (left T))))
     ((eq? (value T) #\-)
           (cons "-" (pre-order (left T))))
     ((eq? (value T) #\/)
           (cons "/" (pre-order (left T))))
     (else (cons (value T) (pre-order (left T))))))
```

Assume that my map function works properly for this. I am working with trees and would like also like to know how to write an arithmetic parse tree in prefix notation. I have done my research on arithmetic parse trees, and I wrote a function that can calculate their value, but I don't know how to traverse them properly for this problem.

Comment: Just answer my question about strings here, I am making a new post about preorder traversals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A String is a sequence of characters. A list of characters can easily be converted to a string.

```
(define charlst '(#\H #\e #\l #\l #\o))
(list->string charlst); ==> "Hello"
```

If you have a list of strings you can `string-append` them:

```
(define stringlst '("A" "B" "C"))
(apply string-append stringlst) ; ==> "ABC"
```

Since it seems you're working with characters it would be easier just using them in the list and `list->string` the result since it's a effortless task for compared to `string-append` which is similar to appending lists.